# LinkedIn access token API returns null values in C#

Tags: linkedin-api

I had integrated the API(Login With LinkedIn) on the web application which is in C# code and it was working fine on the live environment and now it's stopped working.

After checking the code and try to post the data on https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken for getting the access token and received the response null from Linkedin API

Here is the code

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            request.AddParameter("code", code);
            request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
            request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", redirectURL);       
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
```

**response.content** is coming null.
Could anyone help me to find what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameters you are using need to go in as a header and not querystring parameter. Try changing addparamter to addheader. It should work fine.

Comment: I have changed the addparamter to addheader but still not working

Comment: Just checked the documentation, it should be a form post. Not sure about how to do a form post using restclient but you can find some help at this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

I have gone to detailed errors and found

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

This is happening from this code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(MySecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | MySecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | MySecurityProtocolType.Tls | MySecurityProtocolType.Ssl3);
```

My Application is build in .Net framework 4.0

Some suggestion found to upgrade the version 4.0 to 4.5 and use this code

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Is there any way we can run this 4.0 framework?